# Is there a tool similar to pflogsumm (Postfix logs parser) for Dovecot?

Tags: monitoring, logging, dovecot

For monitoring my Postfix install I'm using [pflogsumm](http://linxnet.com/downloads/pflogsumm-faq.txt), which parses the Postfix's logs and generates a nice summary.

I tried to find a similar tool for Dovecot, but couldn't. Is there such a thing?

Some clarifications:

1. The tool has to be open source.
2. We're using Dovecot only for POP3 protocol.

Comment: No there is not. What should that summaries show? "How many mails are displayed per user?" "How many mails did a user move to a trash folder?"

Comment: No, more like how many connections served, how many bad logins, from which IPs were most of connections and other information like this.

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin already available for [logwatch](http://sourceforge.net/projects/logwatch/) which will parse dovecot log files.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a log analyzer for Dovecot that just analyzes connections, IPs, errors and the like, then you can do this with Sawmill and the [Dovecot Sawmill Plugin](http://www.sawmill.net/formats/dovecot_pop_imap.html).

Comment: Thanks, but we're looking for an open source solution. Also we're not using Dovecot for IMAP but for POP3 (I've added these clarifications in the question now).

Comment: @arikfr Then `grep` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Octopussy](https://github.com/Octopussy-Project/Octopussy) project (disclaimer : my project).

It can handle any kind of logs.

It's clearly longer to make it works, but you can do a **lot** more when you've done !